# Two vlookup functions in one cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have following business case and would like to automatizate it with excel. In the first table I have building, renter, start date, end date and rent. In the second cashflow tab, I would like to add how big was the rent for each month and building.

Tab 1.

| Building | Renter | Startdate | Enddate | Rent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | David | 1.1.2021 | 31.07.2021 | 1234 |
| Second | Adam | 1.1.2020 | 31.07.2021 | 3333 |
| Third | George | 1.1.2020 | 31.07.2021 | 4444 |
| First | John | 1.1.2020 | 31.12.2020 | 9999 |

Tab 2

| Building | December 2020 | January 2021 | February 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 9999 | 1234 | 1234 |
| Second | 3333 | 3333 | 3333 |
| Third | 4444 | 4444 | 4444 |

In other words, first I need to find correct building in the first tab and then who was the renter for specific month and fill the value of rent.

Thank you

Comment: Google-sheet or excel? For `TAB 2` headers are date of string texts.

Comment: Yeah, but I can use date - 15.12.2020. Rents are allways for full month.

Comment: Your `TAB 2` has no `Renter` name. So, how you would determine rent for renter. In `TAB 1` building First and Renter John has rent 9999. How you will get this result?

Comment: Based on building. I have to find who was the renter (based on that how big was the rent). So about that 9999 - first I know that is building first, so I go to tab1 and find all rows for building first. And then I need to find correct row where tab2 date is between startdate and endate in tab1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using VLOOKUP (at all, ever. INDEX/MATCH does exactly the same thing but is faster and more versatile).

But in this case, you should be able to for what you want with a simple MAXIFS:

[image]

```
=MAXIFS($E$2:$E$5,$A$2:$A$5,$A9,$C$2:$C$5,"<="&B$8,$D$2:$D$5,">"&B$8)
```

What this does is select the highest rent (should only be one anyway), where the building matches, and the first day of the month falls between the start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

Base on start date:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Tab 2'!1:1000,MATCH(C2,'Tab 2'!1:1,0),FALSE)
```

Base on end date:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Tab 2'!1:1000,MATCH(EOMONTH(D2,-1)+1,'Tab 2'!1:1,0),FALSE)
```